# How to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^n \frac{e^x}{(e^x+1)^2} dx$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to evaluate $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^n \frac{e^x}{(e^x+1)^2} dx?$$

This integral is in the context of solid-state physics, specifically the Sommerfield expansion. Does it have an easy solution, perhaps in terms of the Zeta function?

Comment: The integrand is bounded by $|x|^ne^x$, so the left tail exists and is finite. Locally around $0$ it exists and is finite for $n>-1$, but for $n\ge-1$ the right tail diverges. For $n<-1$ the right tail is fine, but for $n\le -1$ we diverge locally around $0$.

Comment: Judging by [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53960/deriving-the-sommerfeld-expansion-by-contour-integration-le-bellac-p-277), what you need to do is actually do a integration by parts before you expand the integrand. This is mainly because the Fermi distribution can't be used as an envelope for power functions, the result will never converge, so people work with the derivative of the Fermi distribution instead, which is concentrated around 0.

Comment: Perhaps is more easy, if you do $\frac{e^x}{e^x +1}=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ then the new integral is $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(\ln z)^n}{z(1+z)}dz$ i guess

Comment: As for how to deal with the resulting integrals, [here is an example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2792896/how-to-evaluate-int-infty-infty-fracx2ex-left1-ex-right2dx?rq=1) on Math.SE.

Comment: I apologize for the typo... I forgot the square in the denominator of the question. Edited the typo. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: @ElliotYu Thanks! Your example for n=2 answers my question. I need to try that approach for n>2 and check the calculation.

Comment: Hint: the integrand has the same parity as $x^n$, so the integral vanishes for odd $n$, whereas for even $n$ the integral is $2\int_0^\infty\frac{x^ne^{-x}dx}{(1+e^{-x})^2}$, which you can show is $n!2\eta(n)$. [We know how to compute that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function#Particular_values), again because $n$ is assumed even.

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a comment*

$$I(n)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^n \frac{e^x}{(e^x+1)^2} dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \frac{x^n}{(e^{x/2}+e^{-x/2})^2} dx=2^{n-1}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{t^n}{\cosh^2 t}dt$$
It is clear that the integral is not zero only for even $n$.
$$I(n)=2^{n-1}\frac{\partial ^n}{\partial \beta^n}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{\beta t}}{\cosh^2 t}dt\,\bigg|_{\beta=0}=2^{n-1}\frac{\partial ^n}{\partial \beta^n}J(\beta)\,\bigg|_{\beta=0}\tag{1}$$
To evaluate $J(\beta)$ we use a standart rectangular contour in the complex plane:

at $R\to\infty\quad -R\to R\to R+i\pi\to-R+i\pi\to -R$

We have one double pole inside the contour (at $z=\frac{i\pi}{2}$).
$$J(\beta)\big(1-e^{\beta\pi i}\big)=2\pi i\underset{z=\frac{i\pi}{2}}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{e^{\beta z}}{\cosh^2z}=-2\pi i\,\beta \,e^{\frac{\beta\pi i}{2}}$$
$$J(\beta)=2\frac{\frac{\pi\beta}{2}}{\sin\frac{\pi\beta}{2}}\tag{2}$$
Putting (2) into (1)
$$\boxed{\,\,I(n)=\pi^n\frac{\partial^n}{\partial s^n}\frac{s}{\sin s}\,\bigg|_{s=0}\,\,}$$
The integral can also be expressed via Bernoulli numbers.

Quick check:

at $\displaystyle n=0\quad I(0)=1$

On the othe hand, $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^x}{(e^x+1)^2} dx=-\frac{1}{1+e^x}\,\bigg|_{-\infty}^\infty=1$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $n$ is a nonnegative integer. Clearly when $n$ is odd, $I_n=0$. For even $n$, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
I_n&=&\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^n \frac{e^x}{(e^x+1)^2} dx\\
&=&2\int_{0}^\infty x^n \frac{e^x}{(e^x+1)^2} dx\\
&=&2\int_{0}^\infty x^n \frac{e^{-x}}{(e^{-x}+1)^2} dx\\
&=&2\int_{0}^\infty x^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(k+1)e^{-(k+1)x}\\
&=&2\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(k+1)\int_{0}^\infty x^ne^{-(k+1)x}\\
&=&2\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(1+k)^{-n}n!\\
&=&2n!\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(1+k)^{-n}\\
&=&n!2^{n+1}(2^n-2)\zeta(n)
\end{eqnarray}
where
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(1+k)^{-n}=2^{n}(2^n-2)\zeta(n) $$
and $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: I recommend to write $\zeta(n)$ instead of $\zeta_n$ and say what $\zeta$ is. Also add some of the missing $dx$s.

Comment: Thank you for telling me.

Comment: You can say that $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt using the Feynman trick. Consider the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{(1+e^x)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x$$
for $a \in (0,2)$. Then
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^n\frac{e^{x}}{(1+e^x)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\right)^n\frac{e^{ax}}{(1+e^x)^2}\Bigg|_{a = 1} \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
The integrand decays sufficiently fast (should probably check this!), so we can interchange the derivatives with the integral and then make the substitution $y := e^x$:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^n\frac{e^{x}}{(1+e^x)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\right)^n \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{(1+e^x)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \, \Bigg|_{a = 1} = \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\right)^n \int_0^{\infty} \frac{y^{a-1}}{(1+y)^2} \, \mathrm{d}y \, \Bigg|_{a = 1}.$$
The latter integral is a standard integral that you can solve via contour integration, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/678627/635596). Thus
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^n\frac{e^{x}}{(1+e^x)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\right)^n \frac{\pi(a-1)}{\sin(\pi(a-1))}\Bigg|_{a = 1}.$$
In principle you can now obtain the value for arbitrary $n$, but the computation gets quite tedious if you want to do it by hand.